# Are there services that specialize in converting design into layout?

Tags: optimization, design

Are there reasonably-priced services that will take a PSD design concept that was created by a local designer and generate at least a first take on decent HTML?

I know what I want (content-first, accessible, semantic HTML, css sprites, optimized JS, etc) but don't have the patience to do it myself :)

Comment: I don't find this question at all inappropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've developed a relationship with a dozen or so freelance designers. Most of them are quite happy to slice a PSD layout into (X)HTML conforming to the standard of my choice. Most also happily convert it into a Wordpress, Drupal , Joomla , etc theme with very little turn-around time.

I'd head to odesk, freelancer.com, etc and put a few projects out for bid. This gets you a roster of talent that you can pick from, whoever happens to be on-line at the time gets the job.

The usual price I pay just for slicing is $15 - $20, and it takes about an hour. Converting to themes goes from $75 - $200, depending on the complexity of the design. Its worth it to me to just pay someone to do what anyone could do, leaving me more time to spend on tasks that only I can do (like getting fresh content out daily, hunting for quality backlinks, etc ..)

Comment: Thanks Tim, good advice about resource allocation. +1 (and we were tied!) :)

Comment: @JasonBirch - Yes, its like we're jogging together or something.

Comment: odesk sounds about right.

Answer (score 1):

There are hundreds/thousands of these services out there. If you google "PSD to HTML" you'll get a bunch. As for specific businesses, i'm not sure if that's appropriate for me to post?

Comment: I guess I should have realized that it would be such a common request.  I'm not sure what the policy is on recommendations for services.  Off to meta...

Comment: I don't think its inappropriate to recommend a service that you are happy with. I would just avoid making links when making the recommendation.